# Adding 2 Case statements

Tags: sql-server, case

I have 2 separate case statements which are producing the correct results:

```
Case when A_staff_Service_Type.type = 'v' 
  then isnull(Indirect_Duration,0)/60.00 else null end
```

The above produces 6.5 for 1 employee.

```
Case when pt_service.service_code = 'N06 ' 
  then isnull(direct_Duration,0)/60.00 else null End
```

The above produces 5.5 for the same employee.

So I have two separate outputs of 6.5 and 5.5. What I would like is the output to be 12. I have tried

Case when A_staff_Service_Type.type = 'v' 
      then isnull(Indirect_Duration,0)/60.00 else null end 
+

Case when pt_service.service_code = 'N06 ' 
      then isnull(direct_Duration,0)/60.00 else null End

But the above results in 0 instead of 12.

This is a query writer within a clinical application based on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Could you specify your database platform, some sample data and expected output? Oh and welcome to the site, Please do the [tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) read through the [help section](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how this site works. especially how to [ask a good question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You will attract more answers and useful feedback.

Comment: If expression `A` yields `6.5` and expression `B` yields `5.5`, then the expression `A+B` will yield `12.0`. No way it can show `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but I *think* you are looking for something like this:

```
Case 
  when A_staff_Service_Type.type = 'v' and pt_service.service_code = 'N06' 
     then isnull(Indirect_Duration,0)/60.00  + isnull(direct_Duration,0)/60.00 
  else null 
end
```

I also don't know if the `AND` is correct for your use-case. Maybe you want an `OR` - but based on the little information you have provided this is impossible to answer.

The obvious answer to "*I want the results added*" is:

```
Case when A_staff_Service_Type.type = 'v' 
  then isnull(Indirect_Duration,0)/60.00 else 0 end 
+
Case when pt_service.service_code = 'N06 ' 
  then isnull(direct_Duration,0)/60.00 else 0 End
```

Comment: and ifadding them, the `else null` should become `else 0`

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I changed the else null to else 0 with the + between both statements and it works.

Comment: @BlueLiner: hmm, the result of adding `null` to something else should result in `null` not `0` - but maybe this is a non-standard behaviour of SQL Server.